# SharePoint BDC Catalog custom sorting

Tags: sharepoint, bdc

Is it possible any kind custom sorting of the column in SharePoint BDC Catalogs. For example string column which contains numeric and character sequences - make order starting as numbers, then by characters. And use this algorithm when Ascending/Descending buttons are pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it depends on the web parts available to you on your server. You can also get excellent sorting through the use of a BDC List web part and jQuery